# Getting access denied when trying to copy/zip C:\Users\Me\Documents via powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, zip

I'm trying to write a script to quickly zip a list of directories and I'm getting an access denied to `'C:\Users\Me\Documents\My Music'`, which I gather is due to it being a symbolic link.

How can I accomplish this and exclude the symbolic links to be able to zip a directory?  I don't think it's permissions related as I'm running as admin, etc.

**Code:**

```
function ZipFiles( $zipfilename, $sourcedir )
{
    Write-Host "Zipping $sourcedir to $zipfilename"
    Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
    $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir, $zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $false)
}

ZipFiles -sourcedir "C:\Users\Me\Documents" -zipfilename "C:\TestZip.zip"
```

**Error:**

> Zipping C:\Users\me\Documents to C:\TestZip.zip
>
> Exception calling "CreateFromDirectory" with "4" argument(s): "Access to the path 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\My Music' is denied."
>
> At line:8 char:5
>
> - [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir, $zipfilenam ...
>     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException

Answer (score 0):

Stab in the dark but, can you set the Source dir like the following?

```
 -sourcedir '\\?\C:\users\Me\Documents'
```